# Does the Redirect directive override configured Aliases

Tags: apache, redirect, virtualhost, httpd.conf, mod-alias

I'm setting up apache 2.4 (docker) as a reverse-proxy to distribute different subdomains to different docker services. I redirect http-requests to https using the `Redirect` directive. One specific URL-path (the part after the domain), however, should not be redicted to https, but served with files from a specific directory. I'm trying to accomplish this using the `Alias` directive, which does not work.

I'm assuming that `Redirect` overrides `Alias`. Is that true?
And how could I accomplish my goal if this is the case?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName service.example.com

    Alias /exception/ /var/www/exception
    Redirect permanent / https://service.example.com/

</VirtualHost>
```

I expected this to work, but it does not.

Comment: But why don't you just remove Redirect from that one VirtualHost?

Comment: Because I want http requests to be redirected to https (for security and convenience)

Comment: Your question states: "One specific domain, however, should not be redirected to https,", why don't you remove Redirect only from that one domain's VirtualHost?

Comment: I mean the part after the domain so the /exception of service.example.com/exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [mod_alias docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html):

> First, all Redirects are processed before Aliases are processed, and
>   therefore a request that matches a Redirect or RedirectMatch will
>   never have Aliases applied. Second, the Aliases and Redirects are
>   processed in the order they appear in the configuration files, with
>   the first match taking precedence.

To make sure that `/exception/` is not matched, use `RedirectMatch` which allows regex patterns:

```
RedirectMatch permanent "^/(?!exception/)(.*)" "https://service.example.com/$1"
```

Comment: Works like a charm. However I had to escape the slashes in the regex like this: `\/`.

Comment: @robfuscator Slashes are not/do not need to be escaped in regex, so you are doing something wrong.